# Prove that $\frac 1z$ is not a uniform limit of polynomial functions on an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, contour-integration, supremum-and-infimum

Let $0<r<R$ and let $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:r\leq|z|\leq R\}$.

Show that there is a positive number $\epsilon>0$ so that for any polynomial $p$,

$sup\{|p(z)-\frac{1}{z}|:z\in A\}\geq\epsilon$

I don't really know how to approach this problem.

My first approach was to work by contradiction:

BWOC,suppose that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $sup\{|p(z)-\frac{1}{z}|:z\in A\}<\epsilon$

Then, I tried getting a circular contour in the region between the two circles:

$\gamma(t)=r'e^{it}$ for $[0,2\pi]$ where $r<r'<R$

and then examining the 2 contour integrals:

$\int_{\gamma}p(z)dz$ and $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz$

But I don't know how to proceed to reach a contradiction.

I then tried applying the Maximum Modulus principle since $p(z)-\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic.

I could then conclude that $|p(z)-\frac{1}{z}|$ reaches its maximum on the boundaries of A. But then I also get stuck...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maximum modulus principle: If a sequence of polynomials converges uniformly in the annulus, it will converge uniformly in the disc $D_R=\{|z|\leq 
R\}$. The uniform limit of analytic functions on a compact is analytic. Since $1/z$ is not analytic on $D_R$ it cannot be their limit.

Comment: You apply the maximum modulus principle to $p_n-p_m$. For every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that if $n,m>N$ then $|p_n(z)-p_m(z)|<\epsilon$ for all $z\in A$, in particular for all $z\in\{|z|=R\}\subset A$. Therefore $|p_n(z)-p_m(z)|<\epsilon$ for all $z\in D_R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\rho \in [r,R]$ and let $\gamma(t) = \rho e^{it}$, a circle around the origin of radius $\rho$.

Then $\int_\gamma p(z) dz = 0$, $\int_\gamma { 1 \over z} dz = 2 \pi i$ and
so $|\int_\gamma (p(z)-{1 \over z}) dz | = 2 \pi$.

Since
\begin{eqnarray}
2 \pi &=& |\int_\gamma (p(z)-{1 \over z}) dz | \\
&=& |\int_0^{2 \pi} (p(\rho e^{it})-{1 \over \rho e^{it}}) i \rho e^{it} dt| \\
&\le& \rho \int_0^{2 \pi} |p(\rho e^{it})-{1 \over \rho e^{it}}|dt \\
&\le& 2 \pi \rho \sup_{|z|=\rho} |p(z)-{1 \over z}|
\end{eqnarray}
we see that $\sup_{|z|=\rho} |p(z)-{1 \over z}| \ge {1 \over \rho}$.

Comment: I am not understanding the last step. How are you moving the modulus inside the integral ? triangle inequality? and I am not quite sure what $|dz|$ means... Could you, please, clarify?

Comment: @jkbestami: I changed the answer to use the path explicitly.

Comment: This is a lot clearer, thank you. However, I still have difficulties with the last part. How come you get to conclude that the sup of the integrand is larger than 1? I'm sure it's obvious, but I can't see it...

Comment: @jkbestami: I added another line to the expansion above.

Comment: oh! I get it now! Thank you so much!

Comment: $\rho$ is missing (the supremum is $\geqslant 1/\rho$).

Comment: @Maxim: Thanks for catching that. Good spot.

Comment: Um, it's still missing in the integrals from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Comment: @Maxim: Fixed, thanks. Its past my bedtime :-).

Comment: In the interest of science, let's get this right. The second and third lines should be $$\left| \int_0^{2 \pi} \left( p(\rho e^{i t}) - {1 \over \rho e^{i t}} \right) i \rho e^{i t} dt \right| $$ and $$ \rho \int_0^{2 \pi} \left| p(\rho e^{i t}) - {1 \over \rho e^{i t}} \right| dt.$$

Comment: @Maxim: Feel free to make further edits as you see fit.